# maximum length of the Name field in document set

Tags: column

the  maximum length of the Name column in document sets is not sufficient for my purpose and it seems that it is not possible to increase its length.

perhaps I can create another column as my name. However, is it possible to assign a random number to the Name of a new document set by default?

what are the possible solutions for my problem regarding the length of document set Name column?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use a default calculated or static value for the Title, then if you needed that column to be a useful number, such as an ID, or other useful information, you could write an event handler for the library to intercept new document events and re-write the title to be whatever was required.